# How to prove (forall x, P x /\ Q x) -> (forall x, P x)

Tags: proof, coq

How does one prove (forall x, P x /\ Q x) -> (forall x, P x) in Coq? Been trying for hours and can't figure out how to break down the antecedent to something that Coq can digest. (I'm a newb, obviously :)

Comment: Are you looking for ∧ (U+2227: LOGICAL AND) and ∀ (U+2200: FOR ALL)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it more quickly by just applying H, but this script 
should be more clear.

```
Lemma foo : forall (A:Type) (P Q: A-> Prop), (forall x, P x /\ Q x) -> (forall x, P x).
intros.
destruct (H x). 
exact H0.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
elim (H x).
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I figured this one out when I found this:

[Mathematics for Computer Scientists 2](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/g52mc2/)

In lesson 5 he solves the exact same problem and uses "cut (P x /\ Q x)" which re-writes the goal from "P x" to "P x /\ Q x -> P x". From there you can do some manipulations and when the goal is just "P x /\ Q x" you can apply "forall x : P x /\ Q x" and the rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

```
Assume ForAll x: P(x) /\ Q(x)
   var x; 
      P(x) //because you assumed it earlier
   ForAll x: P(x)
(ForAll x: P(x) /\ Q(x)) => (ForAll x: P(x))
```

Intuitivly, if for all x, P(x) AND Q(x) hold, then for all x, P(x) holds.

Answer (score -1):

here is the answer:

```
Lemma fa_dist_and   (A : Set) (P : A -> Prop) (Q: A -> Prop): 

(forall x, P x) /\ (forall x, Q x) <-> (forall x : A, P x /\ Q x).

Proof.

split.

intro H.

(destruct H).

intro H1.

split.

(apply H).

(apply H0).

intro H.

split.

intro H1.

(apply H).

intro H1.

(apply H).

Qed.
```

you can find other solved exercises in this file: https://cse.buffalo.edu/~knepley/classes/cse191/ClassNotes.pdf

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! All your contributions to this site are welcome, but please avoid answering an old post that has already a correct answer, especially as you do not answer the original question.